# Sharing keyboard and mouse between two boxes

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, kvm-switch

I have a Mac and PC that I need to share the USB keyboard and mouse connections with.  They each have a separate monitor.

I think a regular KVM switch is overkill because of the separate monitors, but the USB switches I've seen appear to only allow for one device to be split-- I've looked at Amazon and other reputable dealers and haven't seen different at least?

Will I need to buy two USB switches, or are there creative ways I can share the keyboard and mouse via USB with one switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is a "Software KVM" like [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/). [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/254648/how-to-control-multiple-computers-with-a-single-keyboard-and-mouse) has a nice write-up on the setup and requirements, but it will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Synergy looks great, I'll have to try it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I used a KVM switch in this setup, just don't use the monitor plug on the switch. Leave the monitors directly connected to the computers and use the KVM switch for the keyboard and mouse only. Plug both the keyboard and mouse into a small USB splitter and you'll only need one switch.